# Troubleshooting duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame

Tags: r, plm

I have the following error code:  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame when I want to create my panel data.

I already know that there are sometimes two duplicate couples but I just don't know how to fix it? Anyone an idea?

```
pdata <- pdata.frame(TestTable, index= c("id","date"))
table(index(pdata), useNA = "ifany")
```

we see that on some dates there are two couples → between 0 and 2

```
View(table(index(pdata), useNA = "ifany"))
```

check again if duplicate couples exist --> TRUE

```
any(table(index(pdata), useNA = "ifany") > 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all duplicate couples (id-time) from your dataset "pdata", you can use the `data.table` package and function `unique` from base R in such way:

```
pdata <- unique(pdata, by = c("id", "date"))
```

or as an alternative:

```
library(data.table)
pdata_unique <- unique(pdata[,  c("id", "date"), with = FALSE])
pdata <- merge(pdata_unique, pdata, by = c("id", "date"), all.x = TRUE)
```